# asp.net MVC antiforgerytoken on exception RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have implimented the AnitforgeryToken with my asp.net MVC forms, and also added the attribute to my login procedure, however when the check failes i wish to redirect to my fraud action rather than an exception page. is this possible within the attribute ????

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute.aspx) will just throw [HttpAntiForgeryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpantiforgeryexception.aspx). You could use the [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) to handle this scenario:

```
[HandleError(
    ExceptionType = typeof(HttpAntiForgeryException), 
    View = "Unauthorized")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SomeActionThatRequiresToken() 
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 21):

In case you do not want to put `[HandleError]` attribute on all actions that have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, you may add a custom filter to your Global filters:

**in Global.asax** under `Application_Start()`:

```cs
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

**and then:**

```cs
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AntiForgeryTokenFilter());
    }
}
```

**AntiForgeryTokenFilter.cs:**

```cs
public class AntiForgeryTokenFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpAntiForgeryException))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/"); // whatever the url that you want to redirect to
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```