# MVC AntiForgeryToken exception - Handle globally

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

In my MVC project, there are multiple actions where security between requests and responses is increased with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute. This works fine. Problems arise when a user keeps the page open for several minutes (I assume 20, (Session State timeout?)) and then sends a request to the server. This causes an error, because the token sent back no longer matches the token on the server.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692852/asp-net-mvc-antiforgerytoken-on-exception-redirecttoaction) question, it can be solved by adding a `HandleError` attribute on each specific action that uses `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

Is there a way to set this globally for the entire website? I'd hate setting it on every action separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can regsiter an `ActionFilter` globally in `global.asax` on `Application_Start()` event.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{ 
    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: WouId this any different from adding it to each Controller manually? Besides being less global of course? I just remembered adding an attribute to the controller adds it for every action.

Comment: Just the same, but for every Controller. There's no sideback. But if you want to register the atribute in every controller but one you can't do it with the global filter. But I think this is not the case, isn't it?